# Complex potential between axes & hyperbola

Tags: complex-analysis, potential-theory

okay so i have searched through the entire net and i only get what is complex potential theory. But no body explain how to solve the question maybe because that's at the basic level. My question is

Find and sketch the potential. Find the complex potential too between the axes (potential 110V) and the hyperbola `xy = 1` (potential 60V).

I know there is some sort of use of Laplace's Equation but i don't know how. And i even don't know how to add the values given. Kindly help needed.

Comment: Sorry, could you give a definition or a reference to a definition for what you call "complex potential"?

Comment: well thats the question of the exercise i have quoted here. Complex potential is like phi (x, y) +i si (x, y) where imaginary part represents the trajectory or the direction and is perpendicular to phi. Thats what i know

Comment: No, that's NOT the question of the exercise: the "complex potential theory" does not have anything to do with Volts and electric charges, so you are probably referring to some concept of complex potential which is used in physics (like complex numbers come into play when studying circuits or holomorphic functions when studying 2d fluid dynamics), but if you don't tell us what A complex potential *in general* should be, we cannot tell you how to solve this problem. Weren't you given bibliographical indications for the course (Electrodynamics?)to which the exercise belong?

Comment: Advanced Engineering Mathematics. (9th Edition) Q.3, Q.14 in Exercise 18.1 and Q.4, Q.7 in Exercise 18.3. U can check it out. And i am still unable to think how it'll be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, first of all, when you refer to a book with such a vague title, you should always give also the author. Then, you could have gone back a few pages and you would have found the definition of complex potential: it is an analytic function $F$ such that $\mathrm{Re}F$ is the usual electric potential.

Now, you are given two equipotential lines: $xy=1$ and $xy=0$ (the two axes) and you need to find a function which has two given (constant) values on them and is harmonic in-between. It is quite obvious to try with something depending on $\phi(x,y)=xy$ and, if you compute $\nabla^2\phi$ you find $0$, so $\phi$ is harmonic. Now, if you set $\Phi(x,y)=Axy+B$ you get your potential having value $A$ on the hyperbola and $B$ on the axes.

To get a holomorphic function you can either solve the equations (which are explained earlier in the book) for a harmonic conjugate, or notice that the function $f(z)=z^2$ has real and imaginary part as follows
$$f(x+iy)=x^2-y^2+2ixy$$
Therefore the function
$$F(z)=-\frac{iA}{2}z^2 + B$$
is the complex potential you are looking for (with the convention of setting to $0$ the imaginary part of the constant term you can add to the harmonic conjugate).

Comment: I can't thank you enough. That solved my problem.